# How can I sync Android with Zune?

Tags: sync, android, zune

I have just bought a shiny new HTC Hero.  Is there any way to get it to sync with the Zune software.  In particular I'm looking at Podcast management.

Comment: the computer is running the Zune software. Valid question IMO.

Comment: Same question targeted at iTunes: [*How can I sync Android with iTunes?*](http://superuser.com/questions/47137/sync-android-with-itunes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Zune Software downloads the Podcasts to a folder, for example:

```
C:\Users\[User Name]\Music\Zune\Podcasts
```

You could point the software for the HTC Hero to pickup the Podcasts from there, if there is software for syncing to the HTC Hero for Music etc, this may work - so the Zune Software would just be a podcatcher for the Podcasts, you'd still have to sync to the HTC Hero using its own software - or compatible solution - the Zune Software can only directly sync to the Zune Devices - but of course can stream / allow access to music the same way Windows Media Player does it.

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible, at now.

But maybe in future Microsoft release API for Zune hardware.