# How can I sync Android with iTunes?

Tags: itunes, sync, android

I have just bought a shiny new HTC Hero.  Is there any way to get it to sync with iTunes.  In particular I'm looking at Podcast management.

Same question targeted at the Zune
[How can I sync Android with Zune?](https://superuser.com/questions/47136/sync-Android-with-Zune)

**Update** I am running Windows, but I feel that Mac users would appreciate this too.

Comment: See [this answer at Android.SE](http://Android.stackexchange.com/questions/1351/Android-and-iTunes/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [doubleTwist](http://www.doubletwist.com) to synchronise with iTunes. It'll do non-[DRM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management) files, so your podcasts should be fine.

Comment: DT is such a pile of crap... it doesn't even understand albums.  You have to manually create a playlist for every single album.

Comment: Initially promising but DT has let me down many times and newer versions have not fixed my problems.

Answer (score 4):

Sailing MediaSync synchronizes playlists, music, and podcasts from iTunes and photos from iPhoto or Aperture on the Mac or Adobe Photoshop Elements or Adobe Photoshop Album SE on Windows. it is free for basic use, a paid version allows for intelligent updates, which is much faster

For the Hero you will need to use 'USB Storage mode'

[Windows](http://www.salling.com/MediaSync/windows/)

[Mac OS](http://www.salling.com/MediaSync/mac/)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using your [T-Mobile G1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_Dream) for podcasts, take a look at [Google Listen](http://listen.googlelabs.com/). You can download the newest podcasts on your Android device without having to synchronise with your computer.

There is also a great application called [iSyncr](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jrtstudio.iSyncr&hl=en) for Mac and PC which synchronises with iTunes.

Comment: Tried that, but the hero I bought is unlocked so no paid or copy-protected apps :(

Answer (score 2):

Yah,the best solution for podcast management is the Google Listen app.  If your looking to manage it on your desktop, Listen integrates with Google Reader, so subscribe to your podcasts in Reader, then you can sync it up with your app.

Answer (score 1):

I use [TuneSync](http://highwindsoftware.com/download.php). It sync's over my Wi-Fi connection. All I had to do is download a small app to my pc and setup the playlists on the Droid.

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe your Android phone directly to podcasts in the iTunes store with Feed Flipper.  This free web-based app will convert any iTunes podcast into a usable RSS feed which can be subscribed to with the Android RSS reader of your choice.  No phone/PC install required.

http://picklemonkey.net/flipper/convert.php

Answer (score 1):

I am working on [an application which can copy an iTunes playlist to an Android device](http://code.google.com/p/lijiecoderepository/wiki/iTunes2AndroidAlphaReleaseNotes).
It is under pre-alpha phase with very simple functionalities.

For basic ideas about this tool, you can refer to my wiki page at Google Code.

Please let me know if you have further suggestion on this tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Syncables' 360](http://www.syncables.com/consumer-products/syncables-360/) Android app. It will wirelessly synchronise your media files and contacts.

The downside - you would need to purchase a PC or Mac application.